# How to debug entry point method for app in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, playframework

After started my aap, in `Eclipse`, i set break poins in different places, run debug - all ok.

But, I need debug entry point (first - that executed) method for my app.

And in this moment i confused - I cant run debug, because, debug need that application started.

I can start debug after app started, but entry method successful execute.

So, i really dont know how debug entry point method.

Please, help me with this problem.

Comment: "I cant run debug, because, debug need that application started" There are two types of debug, one where you launch the app in debug mode and one when you remote debug. When you remote debug you application needs to be running and configured for remote debug. Which one are you doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the `main()` method (your entry point) code, you can setup a [Method Breakpoint](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#advanced_method) in order to stop the debug session *just* before entering `main()`:

[image: Method Breakpoint]